# how to bind/render {{...}} html code with innerHtml in angular

Tags: angular, http

i am trying to bind/render html content with innerHTML but not able to render {{...}} in angular.

code as below:

```
<div [innerHtml]="TestString"></div>

test = " HTML Content ";
TestString = "<div>This is test code, i am trying to bind/render {{ test }} code with angular..,</div>";
```

**result**

This is test code, i am trying to bind/render {{ test }} code with angular..,

not binding/render test variable value....

Comment: You can also concatenate strings in your .ts file `TestString = '<div>This is test code, i am trying to bind/render' + this.test +' code with angular..,</div>'`

Answer (score 7):

Try this way:

```
test = " HTML Content ";
TestString = `<div>This is test code, i am trying to bind/render ${this.test} code with angular..,</div>`
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ckxsp8?file=src/app/app.component.ts

If you want to evaluate template from string inside a component, You can create your own directive that will do it:

compile.directive.ts

```
import {
  Compiler, NgModule, Component, Input, ComponentRef, Directive, 
  ModuleWithComponentFactories, OnChanges, Type,
  ViewContainerRef
} from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Directive({
  selector: '[compile]'
})
export class CompileDirective implements OnChanges {
  @Input() compile: string;
  @Input() compileContext: any;

  compRef: ComponentRef<any>;

  constructor(private vcRef: ViewContainerRef, private compiler: Compiler) {}

  ngOnChanges() {
    if(!this.compile) {
      if(this.compRef) {
        this.updateProperties();
        return;
      }
      throw Error('You forgot to provide template');
    }

    this.vcRef.clear();
    this.compRef = null;

    const component = this.createDynamicComponent(this.compile);
    const module = this.createDynamicModule(component);
    this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(module)
      .then((moduleWithFactories: ModuleWithComponentFactories<any>) => {
        let compFactory = moduleWithFactories.componentFactories.find(x => x.componentType === component);

        this.compRef = this.vcRef.createComponent(compFactory);
        this.updateProperties();
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  updateProperties() {
    for(var prop in this.compileContext) {
      this.compRef.instance[prop] = this.compileContext[prop];
    }
  }

  private createDynamicComponent (template:string) {
    @Component({
      selector: 'custom-dynamic-component',
      template: template,
    })
    class CustomDynamicComponent {}
    return CustomDynamicComponent;
  }

  private createDynamicModule (component: Type<any>) {
    @NgModule({
      // You might need other modules, providers, etc...
      // Note that whatever components you want to be able
      // to render dynamically must be known to this module
      imports: [CommonModule],
      declarations: [component]
    })
    class DynamicModule {}
    return DynamicModule;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent {

  name = 'Product Name :'
  price = '3'
  template: string = `{{ name }} <b>{{ price }}$</b>`;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="product">
  <ng-container *compile="template; context: this"></ng-container>
</div>
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eipbup?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: thanks and above code is working fine but i am trying something else as below:

Comment: what exactly do you need?

Comment: want to iterate object

Comment: check this out : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ck7h8q?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Check this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xhbmhf?file=src/app/app.module.ts
Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks dear for helping me out i am new to angular... thanks a lot again... have a good time

Comment: getting error while executing in production mode                                                                                     main-es2015.6229e97a4e22e893263a.js:1 ERROR Error: Runtime compiler is not loaded
    at Ei.Oi (main-es2015.6229e97a4e22e893263a.js:1)
    at $f.ngOnChanges (main-es2015.6229e97a4e22e893263a.js:1)
    at main-es2015.6229e97a4e22e893263a.js:1
    at main-es2015.6229e97a4e22e893263a.js:1
    at el (main-es2015.6229e97a4e22e893263a.js:1)
    at Pl (main-es2015.6229e97a4e22e893263a.js:1)
    at Object.updateDirectives (main-es2015.6229e97a4e22e893263a.js:1)

Comment: Hey @SunilPune could you solve this? or what was your plan b for this problem?

Comment: DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eipbup?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html ,       Check this: stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xhbmhf?file=src/app/app.module.ts      solved by @BartoszTermena

Comment: getting error while executing in production mode main-es2015.6229e97a4e22e893263a.js:1 ERROR Error: Runtime compiler is not loaded at Ei.Oi (main-es2015.6229e97a4e22e893263a.js:1) at $f.ngOnChanges (main-es2015.6229e97a4e22e893263a.js:1) at main-es2015.6229e97a4e22e893263a.js:1 at main-es2015.6229e97a4e22e893263a.js:1 at el (main-es2015.6229e97a4e22e893263a.js:1) at Pl (main-es2015.6229e97a4e22e893263a.js:1) at Object.updateDirectives (main-es2015.6229e97a4e22e893263a.js:1)